# I just installed Minecraft and my sound doesn't work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just installed Minecraft and my sound doesn't work.  All sound settings in-game are 100% and when I open mixer in my sound on Task Bar it doesn't show Minecraft at all. Can you please help? I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: Check to make sure your playback device that is selected in Windows is to a valid output. https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-change-default-playback-recording-audio-device

Comment: My overall sound works just fine but when I play Minecraft it doesn't show in the mixer!

Comment: Do you have multiple devices to select from in the mixer? It could be that Minecraft is outputting it to the wrong device.

Answer (score 1):

If your sound on your computer works, just not minecraft, this solution may work.   Open minecraft and press <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. This will reload resource packs which sometimes fixes the sound. Sounds weird but sometimes works. My Minecraft will load with no sound once in a while and this fixes it.

Comment: F3 + T trick didn't work thank you for suggestion